# How do I get static expression ActionLinks etc in ASP.NET MVC 1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've read loads of examples in which

```
<li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
```

is rewritten as

```
<li><%= Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(c => c.Index(), "Index")%></li>
```

However, with a fresh ASP MVC project, this doesn't compile. I've read its something to do with needing to add the ASP MVC Futures assembly. Is this correct and if so, where do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need the ASP.NET MVC Futures assembly, it's available here for 1.0:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471